# Is there a way to programatically put Chrome browser into kiosk mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app

I'm writing a Chrome app that needs to be run fullscreen and prevent users from exiting full screen (i.e. kiosk mode). Right now, the only thing I've been able to find is the command-line switch but the people managing this app will not be able to figure out a command line. Is there another way to force this?

Answer (score 1):

With a packaged app it is possible to go to fullscreen programmatically using `chrome.app.window.current().fullscreen()` or similar from which the user cannot exit using ESC or F11.

See http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/apps/api_other.html

Comment: Yes, but they can exit it with `Alt+Tab`. I've found no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you are after is possible with the current chrome-app APIs.

But as an alternative, why not provide the people managing the app a windows batch file (or equivalent for OSX) to run chrome with the required command line arguments ?